# Command Line Interface with C - How does scanf work?

Tags: c, command-line, terminal, scanf

**Important edit: From the comments below, I understood that you guys didn't notice any problem with my code below. I've used a scanf(%c, &[a char variable]) to feed in more than one character before hitting enter on the commandline, and the scanf didn't work as it normally would when I tried using it the SECOND TIME. The SECOND TIME I used scanf and entered something on the commandline, IT DID NOT TAKE IN THE INPUT I had just entered. INSTEAD IT STORED WHATEVER WAS REMAINING FROM THE FIRST LINE OF INPUT.**

Okay, so I was messing around with my C code yesterday. I ran the following code to see what would happen if I were to feed in a word in instead of a letter like I'm supposed to (Since I declared a char and not a char array or a string.)

Apperently if you feed in more than one letter, It will **remember the remaining letters that it failed to take in as an input** and then **assign it to the variable you'll to use for assignment in your next scanf statement**

P.S. I didn't use a for loop **on purpose.**

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? How does scanf work? **And if the remaining input is not discarded, how exactly is it saved in the memory?**

```
char word;

printf("start %d\n", 1);
scanf("%c", &word);
printf("%c\n\n", word);
printf("start %d\n", 2);
scanf("%c", &word);
printf("%c\n\n", word);
printf("start %d\n", 3);
scanf("%c", &word);
printf("%c\n\n", word);
printf("start %d\n", 4);
scanf("%c", &word);
```

Comment: You only consume 1 character from the input stream. Why would you expect that all the remaining input is just discarded?

Comment: Perhaps read the `scanf` [docs](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), which will explain exactly why the stream continues.

Comment: You just found out how `scanf` works. Why would remaining input be discarded? That would mean you could use it only once per file/program. That would be silly.

Comment: @Cheatah I don't think you understand what I'm trying to get at here. You should try running my code, so that you can understand what the problem with it is. The problem here is that if you use 1| scanf %c &a (a is a char here) and feed more than one character (like a whole sentance before hitting enter on the commandline), your next line of input on the commandline won't be considered. That is, if you use 2| scanf %c &b, whatever you feed in this time on the commandline won't be considered. It will instead take the remaining characters from what you entered the first time.

Comment: I know perfectly well what happens and what is to be expected when running your code. You seem to think that scanf should work with lines of input. It doesn't, it works with characters, and a newline character is just a character. It is in the category of whitespace characters, which makes it somewhat special, but you are making quite some assumptions. What you probably want is line-based input, for that I would recommend `fgets`, and then parse that line, potentially with `sscanf` but preferably with something more advanced.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` does not manage any of the work of reading from your terminal or console or from other devices.

In C, the standard input, standard output, and standard error are *streams*, and a program can open other streams manually. Streams are constructions (software, data, and algorithms) for managing connections to files and devices. They are implemented by other parts of the C standard I/O routines, such as `fopen` and `fgetc`.

When you call `scanf`, it gets one character at a time from the stream and attempts to match it to the conversions you have requested. As it finds matches, it stores data in the objects you have passed it. When it gets a character that is not acceptable for the conversion it is working on, it “puts it back” into the stream.

Streams may be buffered or unbuffered. If a stream is buffered, the stream software reads some amount of data from the file or device and keeps it in an internal array of characters. When `scanf` or other routines request one or more characters from the stream, the stream software provides the requested data from its array. The stream keeps track of how much data it has buffered. When the buffer is empty and more data is requested, the stream software reads more data from the file or device. Buffered streams can be *fully buffered* or *line buffered*. With a fully buffered stream, the software attempts to completely fill the buffer before performing another I/O operation with the file or device. With a line buffered stream, the software receives or sends one line at a time.

Even unbuffered streams maintain a buffer of at least one byte. This enables the “put back” capability. When `scanf` or another routine “puts back” a character, the stream software remembers it and, when a character is requested in the future, it returns that character first.

In spite of its name, the `FILE` object in C manages a stream. When `fopen`, for “file open,” is called, it opens a stream. The “file” part is legacy from the history of computing; if we were starting it over, we might call it “sopen” for “stream open.” `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` point to `FILE` objects for streams that are automatically opened when the program starts. `fclose` closes a stream. `fgetc` and `fputc` read and write individual characters from a stream. There are variations of these routines, like `getchar`, that read from `stdin`. `fread` and `fwrite` read and write multiple characters at a time. These are the direct input/output routines.

`scanf` is one of the formatted input/output routines. It uses `getchar`, `fread`, or equivalents to get the characters, and then it performs additional operations to do the matching and conversions. When it finishes performing the conversions you request, it stops reading. The unread data remains in the stream. `scanf` does not take any action to read and discard the rest of the line, unless you explicitly request it with something in the format string that will match the rest of the line.